# Generate random numbers with distribution e^x

Tags: r, distribution

Is there any way to generate random numbers of the distribution e^x with x defined over a certain range in R?

Comment: As such this is not a distribution. What range are you talking about? density is equla to e^x between 0 to ln(2) and 0 elsewhere ?

Comment: What is the distribution of x? Is it uniform?

Comment: the range is from 0 to 0.5 but there's a constant 1/((e^0.5) -1)

Comment: The distribution of x is uniform because I'm just taking the conditional distribution at a certain point.

Comment: `exp(runif(n, 0, 0.5))`?

Comment: Man you talk about the distribution e^x. What is your definition domain for x?

Comment: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/26693_e1151035722942b2813c0063c6b220ae.html

Comment: The domain for x is [0, 0.5]

Comment: @Roland wouldn't that just give random values of the uniform distribution though? I'm looking for e^x.

Comment: you do not defined a distribution this way. Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear, so I'm going to assume that you'd like to treat e<sup>x</sup> as a density.  The function e<sup>x</sup> on the range (0,0.5) is not a density, because densities are required to have an area of 1.  However, over any specified finite range it can be scaled by its area to turn it into a density.  Integrating e<sup>x</sup> over the specified range yields e<sup>x</sup>/0.6487212707001282 as a valid density (to within roundoff error).

We then integrate the density from 0 to `x` for 0 ≤ x ≤ 0.5 to derive the cumulative distribution function:  F(x) = (e<sup>x</sup> - 1) / 0.6487212707001282.

we can now use [inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) to generate values from this distribution.  Set the CDF equal to U, a Uniform(0,1) random number, and solve for x:

```
 x = ln(1 + 0.6487212707001282 * U)
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to leave the constant as `exp(0.5)-1` ?

Comment: @BenBolker if you want to do that I'd express it as `exp(upper_limit) - exp(lower_limit)` to keep it fully general.  I chose to translate it so OP wouldn't be tempted to evaluate it over and over when generating lots of these things.